# Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/foldername/innerfolder/Info.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a custom module, Grid section is working fine, I want to view the data in my custom tab,

This is my code.

app/code/local/Folder/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Adminquote/View/Tabs.php

```
$this->addTab("form_section", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("adminquote")->__("Quotation Details"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("adminquote")->__("Quotation Details"),
        "content" => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("adminquote/adminhtml_adminquote_view_tab_info")->toHtml(),
        "active" => true
));
```

app/code/local/Folder/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Adminquote/View/Tab/Info.php

```
class Folder_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Adminquote_View_Tab_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->setTemplate('adminquote/view/info.phtml');
    }
}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminquote.xml

```
<adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_tab_info>
<reference name="content">
   <action method="addTab">
      <name>adminhtml_adminquote_view_tab</name>
      <block>adminquote/adminhtml_adminquote_view_tab_info</block>
   </action>
 </reference>
```

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Folder_Modulename>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Folder_Modulename>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <Folder_Modulename>
            <class>Folder_Modulename_Block</class>
        </Folder_Modulename>
    </blocks>
</global>       
<adminhtml>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <modulename>
                <file>adminquote.xml</file>
            </modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

I am getting error in system.log

```
2019-01-09T11:52:36+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/adminquote/view/Info.phtml
```

Info.phtml file exists in that path.

I don't know why its showing template not valid, Can anyone suggest me to fix this,

Thanks.

Comment: Paste your module config.xml too

Comment: @Raghul Sanchez, I have updated my config.xml, please check.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong in your layout file

```
<adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminquote/adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info" name="adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info" />
    </reference>
</adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info>
```

The identifier `adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info` should correspond to a controller action, or a layout handle. You'd fix that first, according to how your module is implemented

I don't see any admin router defined in your **config.xml** file, so I suppose you want to inject your custom tab in an existing Magento module. If that's the case, here you have an example about how to do that https://makandracards.com/magento/10947-add-a-tab-to-the-admin-product-screen

Next, your block type is wrong

According to the **config.xml** you've pasted the block type should be `Folder_Modulename/adminhtml_adminquote_view_tabs_info` (capital letters are totally relevant, unless you are working under a Windows system... and I hope that's not your case). This applies both for the layout file & the class where you define the block for your tab (**app/code/local/Folder/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Adminquote/View/Tabs.php**)

Once this 2 problems are fixed, the template path loaded by application should be **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/adminquote/view/Info.phtml** (again, capital letters are totally relevant)

Comment: @rahul Sanchez, The identifier adminquote_adminhtml_adminquote_view_Tabs_Info should correspond to a controller action or a layout handle. Can you please explain this.

Comment: As my understanding, it does not correspond to the controller action. (If you need module code, I can zip it and send to you.)

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/design/layout-updates.html

Comment: I went through the link as you mentioned above,

Comment: In my custom module form edit and update are working fine, I just want to view my data like order view page. For that only it's giving an error. Layout updates are working for edit and updates.

Comment: @rahul Sanchez, I have updated my app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminquote.xml code.